# Latest CMake on Ubuntu 16.04 without removing other packages

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, cmake

I need to use new version of CMake because of cmake_minimum_required usage in the CMakeLists. I have Ubuntu 16.04 and CMake 3.5.2. I performed the steps for "Installing CMake from Source Code" from the https://www.osetc.com/en/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-cmake-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-linux.html Unfortunately I lost some important packages - removed together with the CMake.

If I try to do it without old CMake removing, the cmake --version shows the correct one (latest) but I'm still getting the error in CMakeLists (it's detecting the old one).

Is possible tu update it without losing packages or should I reinstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of installing cmake from source, why don't you try adding CMake deb repository:
https://apt.kitware.com/

In this way you will install the latest version of cmake in the proper way.